# Grammar with a long derivation generates an infinite language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> Let $G$ be a CFG in Chomsky normal form that contains $b$ variables. Show that if $G$
>   generates some string with a derivation having at least $2^b$ steps, then $L(G)$ is infinite.

This question is from Sipser(Introduction to the theory of computation)

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this question?

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?  Please credit the source of all copied material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the pumping lemma, if you examine the proof closely enough.

Comment: Thx for the tip. So here are my thoughts.
Since we have b variables, the height of the parsing tree can be maximum b +1, therefore for a word which is at least of length $2^b$ there must be a repeated nonterminal on this branch which I can pump up

Comment: Right, that's the idea.